# How can I show just code section of my github repository code (without other part just code) in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, github, repository, github-integration

New here. How can I show just code from my repository in Flutter app like we see on many websites?

Comment: What do you mean by show code? Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you mean by  just code? Can you include some visual?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.